# Recurring payments using checkout call and checkout UI in square connect

Tags: square-connect

I already integrate Square api in .net application using 'checkout' api.

```
https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/" + locationID + "/checkouts
```

and checkout UI provided by Square (`https://connect.squareup.com/v2/checkout?c=XXXXX`).
It is working fine now. 
My new functionality is to subscribe a plan and pay using the square. When i search, I found out that I need to create customer and customercard and need to charge the customer card by using 'charge' api.
Is there any provision to use the 'checkout' api for the subscription...? If it is no, Is there any built in UI for charge api implementation...?
whether I need to implement my own UI for capturing the card details...?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no provision for using the checkout API for recurring payments at this moment.

There is no pre-built UI for the charge API, that is essentially what the Checkout API is.

You will need to implement your own UI using the [PaymentForm](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/adding-payment-form) as well as some way to capture customer details so that you can create a customer to attach the card nonce to.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks tristansokol.....  How will i implement promocode functionality using charge API...? Is it enough by using charge with delay_capture and 'VoidTransaction' / 'CaptureTransaction'... Please help..

Comment: If you want to charge a discounted price, just send a lower value to the charge endpoint.

Comment: how the renewal of recurring payments using square connect will work...? What i need to do for the auto renewal functionality after the subscription period ends...?